# Mellanox NICs listed in lspci & lshw but not in ip link

Tags: ubuntu, mellanox

Ubutnu 20.04

Mellanox ConnectX-5 100G NICs

I see the Mellanox NICs when running `lspci` and `lshw` but i don't see them listed when looking at `ip link show`

When looking at lshw for other NICs on the system i see a `logical interface` like `eno1` but for the Mellanox devices i don't see that.  I only have IPMI access so can't easily download anything as the mgmt port is not connected.

Could this just be a driver issue or something else?
Here is a sceenshot of the `lshw` section for the Mellanox NICs https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUmL1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's a driver issue, they are not included, you need to download them from nvidia site.

I had the same issue (with CentOS) with Mellanox ConnectX-6 Lx.

I was installing CentOS, so I followed this approach: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/updating-drivers-during-installation_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user